# $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 $ s.t. $|x-a| < \epsilon => |f(x)-f(a)| < \delta$ Is $f$ continuous in R?

Tags: calculus

**My Thoughts**: I think the statement is not corrent. I want to take a big $\delta$ s.t. the condition will take place but a function that has no limit like Dirichlet. Those are only thoughts can someone help me please to formalize it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want your function to be continuous? How can we know if its incorrect without knowing what correct would be? for continuous, you should interchange $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ after the $s.t$

Comment: @AndresMejia editing sorry forgot to include that

Comment: Just pick a discontinuous function and look at the point of discontinuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
has the property
$$\forall \epsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0\,\forall x\in\Bbb R\,\bigl( |x-a|<\epsilon\to |f(x)-f(a)|<\delta\bigr) $$
(no matter what $a\in\Bbb R$ you pick)
because we simply might pick $\delta=2$ no matter what $\epsilon$ is. But of course $f$ is not continuous (in fact, is nowhere continuous).

Answer (score 0):

Any bounded function satisfies this property. In fact, I believe it is equivalent to local boundedness.